# Any advantages if we use multiple database instead of only one in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to get the suggestion for my usecase.

We have a database in our production machine.We are doing continuous writes in that database since we are doing crawling,parsing and it is being inserted into database as a streamer.We are running some crons on the database.That database gets some reads for the web application also.

I got the requirement just to store the html document into one another table for the cross verification.So,the plan was to store the pages into one new table which was created in the same database.Here we need to run one more cron on the new table to find the page number and update into that table.

We got one more idea like to create the table and running cron in new database instead of the old database by considering performance improvement.

Will it be any difference to create a new database and update into it rather than using old database to update the data and running a cron?

we are using amazon ec2 medium instance with Ubuntu operating system also PostgreSQL 8.4.

your thoughts please?

Comment: In PostgreSQL there is no native support for cross-database queries.  There is an extension called `dblink`, but it is not very handy.  Of course, you can fetch pieces of data from two or more databases in an application.  Either way, it adds considerable complexity, which is worth IMHO only when you face performance problems and the usual optimisation approaches do not yield sufficient results.

Comment: "more write loads into only one DB"  and "share the writes by creating another new DB "        What are the  different effect it will produce in terms of performance?

Comment: It is a bit more complex than this.  I'd expect that reorganizing your database physically (say using different tablespaces and respective hard disks (or arrays)) would have much greater effect than split it logically into two databases.

Comment: what, exactly, are these cronjobs doing? additionally, have you measured the actual impact of everything that is going on?

Comment: We store the html pages.The cron will take html page and parse for page_no count updating into table.another con will move the required data into another table.only two crons

Comment: @dezso: Can you put tablespaces on different disks or arrays if you're running on Amazon EC2?

Comment: @NavaneethanRamasamy: Is upgrading to a 9.x version of PostgreSQL possible?

Comment: @Catcall you can attach another EBS volume to the EC2 instance but I think that, in theory, IO separation on an EC2 instance shouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: @catcall we have to try upgrading to latest..will this give a difference?

Comment: @NavaneethanRamasamy Any improvement on this?

Comment: @dezso Yeah..We got good experience on this.The two days back we had executed like 4 crons in database,each is used for various purpose.So unfortunately the instance got down.So, The plan was we splitted the cron workers and one set of cron will be handled by one new node(machine) and other set will be handled by same node. These two nodes has been connected over netowrk in postgresql.So,Here may be input read and write would be the same.So We are not seeing any side effects to database still.We are on the way to grade our databse.Now bit track turned.

Answer (score 2):

If it needs to be cross-verified, put it in the same db.  That way you can do your cross-verification in the db, taking advantage of indexes, query optimization, etc. which you can't do as easily in separate db's without a fair bit of extra work.

In theory you can spread out your disk/IO loads by putting it in another machine but typically, if this is virtually all write, I don't think it will be worth it.

If it is a different db on the same machine, you will not get any better write performance and you will likely get worse read performance.